# Adding text to a rectangle that can be resized, and moved on Pygame without addons

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to blit text onto a rectangle which can move and readjust its size.
I was thinking on making the rectangle a surface and just blitting the text on the surface, but I do not know how to do so :(

The rectangle that can move around and be able to be resized is:

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
rect1 = pg.Rect(100, 100, 161, 100)
rect2 = pg.Rect(300, 200, 161, 100)
selected_rect = None

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            for rect in (rect1, rect2):
                if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    selected_rect = rect  # Select the colliding rect.
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            selected_rect = None  # De-select the rect.
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
            if selected_rect is not None:  # If a rect is selected.
                if event.buttons[0]:  # Left mouse button is down.
                    # Move the rect.
                    selected_rect.x += event.rel[0]
                    selected_rect.y += event.rel[1]
                else:  # Right or middle mouse button.
                    # Scale the rect.
                    selected_rect.w += event.rel[0]
                    selected_rect.h += event.rel[1]
                    selected_rect.w = max(selected_rect.w, 10)
                    selected_rect.h = max(selected_rect.h, 10)

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    pg.draw.rect(screen, (0, 100, 250), rect1)
    pg.draw.rect(screen, (0, 200, 120), rect2)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Also if possible can anyone help me with the rectangles a bit, They seem to be able to move off the screen, how is it possible to make the screen size the border and make the rectangles bounce off of it?

Comment: Please add some more information. What exactly do you want to do in your game? Do you want only a single line of text or multiple lines? In your previous comment you said that the text should wrap. What exactly does that mean to you? Also, will the text always stay the same or can it change as well?

Comment: And should the text be scaled or be wrapped around the rect or both?

Comment: I have multiple lines and I want the text to adjust accordingly to the rectangle size so it doesn't get out of it. I would like the font and size of the text to stay constant.

Comment: Its not exactly multiple lines, its kinda like when you type of google docs, the words will go to the next line. I'm trying to type a paragraph into the rectangle.

Comment: I was thinking on using `selected_rect.w` and `selected_rect.h` but I'm not sure how to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic solution. I start by splitting the text into separate words. Then, to create the lines, I add one word after the other to an intermediary list (`line`) and use the `pygame.font.Font.size` method to get the size of the word which I add to the `line_width` variable. When the `line_width` exceeds the rectangle width, I use the words in the line list to render a text surface and append it to the `self.images` list.

To blit the text surfaces, I enumerate the `self.images` and then multiply the index by the height of the font to shift the surfaces.

```
import pygame as pg


class TextBox:

    def __init__(self, text, pos, font, bg_color, text_color=(255, 255, 255)):
        self.font = font
        self.font_height = font.get_linesize()
        self.text = text.split()  # Single words.
        self.rect = pg.Rect(pos, (200, 200))
        self.bg_color = bg_color
        self.text_color = text_color
        self.render_text_surfaces()

    def render_text_surfaces(self):
        """Create a new text images list when the rect gets scaled."""
        self.images = []  # The text surfaces.
        line_width = 0
        line = []
        space_width = self.font.size(' ')[0]

        # Put the words one after the other into a list if they still
        # fit on the same line, otherwise render the line and append
        # the resulting surface to the self.images list.
        for word in self.text:
            line_width += self.font.size(word)[0] + space_width
            # Render a line if the line width is greater than the rect width.
            if line_width > self.rect.w:
                surf = self.font.render(' '.join(line), True, self.text_color)
                self.images.append(surf)
                line = []
                line_width = self.font.size(word)[0] + space_width

            line.append(word)

        # Need to render the last line as well.
        surf = self.font.render(' '.join(line), True, self.text_color)
        self.images.append(surf)

    def draw(self, screen):
        """Draw the rect and the separate text images."""
        pg.draw.rect(screen, self.bg_color, self.rect)

        for y, surf in enumerate(self.images):
            # Don't blit below the rect area.
            if y * self.font_height + self.font_height > self.rect.h:
                break
            screen.blit(surf, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y+y*self.font_height))

    def scale(self, rel):
        self.rect.w += rel[0]
        self.rect.h += rel[1]
        self.rect.w = max(self.rect.w, 30)  # 30 px is the minimum width.
        self.rect.h = max(self.rect.h, 30)
        self.render_text_surfaces()

    def move(self, rel):
        self.rect.move_ip(rel)
        self.rect.clamp_ip(screen.get_rect())


text = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."""
pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
FONT = pg.font.Font(None, 34)
selected_box = None
textbox = TextBox(text, (50, 50), FONT, (20, 50, 120))
textbox2 = TextBox(text, (350, 100), pg.font.Font(None, 22), (20, 80, 60))

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            for box in (textbox, textbox2):
                if box.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    selected_box = box  # Select the colliding box.
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            selected_box = None  # De-select the box.
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
            if selected_box is not None:  # If a box is selected.
                if event.buttons[0]:  # Left mouse button is down.
                    selected_box.move(event.rel)
                else:
                    selected_box.scale(event.rel)

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    textbox.draw(screen)
    textbox2.draw(screen)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

There are still some things that need to be improved, but I leave that to you. For example:

- Words that are wider than the width of the rect stick out.
- Paragraphs are ignored.
- I just omit lines that are below the rect.
- If you want to change the text, you should add a getter and a setter method or properties in which you call the `render_text_surfaces` method to update the surfaces.

Comment: It says `builtins.AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'scale'` when i try to put it in my program...

Comment: That probably happens because `selected_box` is a `TextBox` object with a `scale` method now not a `pygame.Rect`. I'd have to see your code in order to help you with the implementation and debugging, but I don't have time now.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [pygame-text](https://github.com/cosmologicon/pygame-text) which simplifies drawing text onto a surface.

Given a surface:

```
surface = pg.Surface((200, 100))
```

You can add text easily enough:

```
import ptext  # Grab the module from Github

ptext.draw("hello world", (20, 100), surf=surface)
screen.get_surface().blit(surface, (10, 10))
```

Plenty more info on the above link.

Comment: I dont want to use another add on, I would just like to only use pygame if possible

Comment: You should mention that you don't want to use add-ons in your question.